# Why does pulse sensor shows gaps when I move it?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

I modified the serial code in this way and I don't think the gap is produced by my edit even because it made it even before:

```
//////////
/////////  All Serial Handling Code, 
/////////  It's Changeable with the 'serialVisual' variable
/////////  Set it to 'true' or 'false' when it's declared at start of code.  
/////////

void serialOutput(){   // Decide How To Output Serial. 
 if (serialVisual == true){  
     arduinoSerialMonitorVisual('-', Signal);   // goes to function that makes Serial Monitor Visualizer
 } else{
      sendDataToSerial('S', Signal);     // goes to sendDataToSerial function
 }        
}


//  Decides How To OutPut BPM and IBI Data
void serialOutputWhenBeatHappens(){    
 if (serialVisual == true){            //  Code to Make the Serial Monitor Visualizer Work
    //ASCII Art Madness
    Serial.print(BPM);
    Serial.println("");

 } else{
        sendDataToSerial('B',BPM);   // send heart rate with a 'B' prefix
        sendDataToSerial('Q',IBI);   // send time between beats with a 'Q' prefix
 }   
}



//  Sends Data to Pulse Sensor Processing App, Native Mac App, or Third-party Serial Readers. 
void sendDataToSerial(char symbol, int data ){
    Serial.print(symbol);

    Serial.println(data);                
  }


//  Code to Make the Serial Monitor Visualizer Work
void arduinoSerialMonitorVisual(char symbol, int data ){    
  const int sensorMin = 0;      // sensor minimum, discovered through experiment
const int sensorMax = 1024;    // sensor maximum, discovered through experiment

  int sensorReading = data;
  // map the sensor range to a range of 12 options:
  int range = map(sensorReading, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 11);

  // do something different depending on the 
  // range value:
  switch (range) {
  case 0:     
    Serial.println("");

  } 
}



63

63
63
63
63
62
62
62
62
62
62
62
63
62
63
64
63
63
64
64
65
65



65
68
74
78
86
95
105
112
123
141
167
154
136
128
123
125
123
127
132
104
93
92
92
89
83
77
73
69
65
70
70
71
```

You can find all the code here:
https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensor_Amped_Arduino

In the code I posted there is some code I don'f find useful but I can't delete it for reason linked to variables used for other functions I don't know I'm using.
You can also see huge changes in the heart rate that surely don't reflect the reality.

Comment: probably because of the badly formatted `switch() case:` statement. Have a look at what the `Serial.println('"");`

Comment: that's where I deleted things

Comment: ok I deleted the code there and now no problem. Any idea on how to fix the erroneous heart rates?

Comment: That might be something with the sensor and how it is connected, loose connections possibly.

Comment: do you mean that it's probably not enough tight on my finger?

Comment: I was talking about the electrical wiring side of loose connections, but also I am sure not having an good attachment to the finger might give bad readings, if its loose try making it tight but not to the point of loosing a finger :)

Comment: probably also the wires to the arduino weren't so fitted.

Comment: if the wires are loose the Analog reading will be very noisy

Comment: noisy in this case means that I will get the values I had?

Comment: Try using another serial terminal program (such as br@y terminal, Hterm, YAT etc.). In these programs you can control the timeout and also view line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is when you move your finger, the sensor grip loosened and doesn't count a "beat". So the sensor emits `data = 0`, and it will cause

```
Serial.println("");
```

in your switch-case.

Comment: Upvote because this seems most likely.  If changing code doesn't matter, and the wiring is intact, then it must be the movement that is causing it.  Like the old joke:  "Doctor, it hurts when I lift my arm" and the Doctor says, "Then don't lift your arm"